# Copy files on post-build events and checkout any target files that were overwritten

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, xcopy, post-build-event

I have two Visual Studio solutions. In one's post-build events, I'm copying some files to a directory of the other solution using `xcopy`.

However, while the file contents is changed on disk, the files are not checked out (I'm using `TFS`), and so I have to manually check which files were changed in the first solution, or just check out all of them each time my post-build runs.

What I would like to do is to have some better logic, that would iterate the files I want to copy, check if they are different on the target path, and then copy and check-out.

How could it be done?

Comment: Why you should do this? Did you only want to confirm the file which overwritten correctly to make sure the synchronization between two solutions without any problem ?

Comment: @Patrick I would like to do this because the copied files (which were modified in the second solution) won't be checked in if I don't automatically know they were changed.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to use [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1). It will show the file status with different icon, such as the file in source control(with green Triangle in the lower left corner ) the file checked out (with a pen)

[image]